# Normalize unicode does not work as expected

Tags: python, unicode, special-characters, normalize

I currently face some problems with different unicode representations of special characters, especially with the ones with accents or diaereses and so on. I wrote a python script, which parses multiple database dumps and compares values between them. The problem is, that in different file, these special characters are stored differently. In some files, these characters are composed, in others decomposed. As I want to have the string extracted from the dump always in the composed representation, I tried adding the following line:

```
value = unicodedata.normalize("NFC", value)
```

However, this solves my problem  the only in some cases. For example, for umlauts it works as expected. Nevertheless, characters like *ë* will remain in the decomposed schema (*e͏̈*).

I figured out, that there is *COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER*-character(U+034F) between the *e* and diaeresis character. Is that normal, or could this be cause the of my problem?

Does anybody know, how to handle this issue?

Comment: I'd say that if you have _COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER_ then there is a reason it's there but it depends on text language (yes, even for diaeresis). I tend to think it's not an error then you shouldn't remove it (unless you want to perform a _relaxed_ comparison) but you should ask to native speakers of that language: it may also be there because of original text processing software, not because of language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `U+034F` COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER is to ensure that certain sequences remain distinct under searching/sorting/normalisation. This is required for the correct handling of characters and combining marks as they are used in some languages with Unicode algorithms. From [section 23.2](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch23.pdf) of the Unicode Standard (page 805):

> U+034F combining grapheme joiner (CGJ) is used to affect the collation
> of adjacent characters for purposes of language-sensitive collation
> and searching. It is also used to distinguish sequences that would
> otherwise be canonically equivalent.
>
> ...
>
> In turn, this means that insertion of a combining grapheme joiner between two combining marks will prevent normalization from switching the positions of those two combining marks, regardless of their own combining classes.

In general, you should *not* remove a CGJ without some special knowledge about why it was inserted in the first place.